# Python openCV matchTemplate Assertation Failed 16 bit images

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to follow this tutorial (below) with 16-bit images. The respective images are in arrays of 231x291 for the 'large image' as img. And array size of 51x107 for the 'small image' as 'selected_img'. However, I keep getting this error.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

```
methods = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_CCORR',
           'cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']
for meth in methods:
    img = img.copy()
    method = eval(meth)
    # Apply template Matching
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, selected_image, method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    # If the method is TM_SQDIFF or TM_SQDIFF_NORMED, take minimum
    if method in [cv2.TM_SQDIFF, cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
    cv2.rectangle(img, top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
    plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(res, cmap='gray')
    plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.suptitle(meth)
    plt.show()
```

Error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-19-61c72dbd3f62>", line 8, in <module>
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, selected_image, method)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1164: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opencv matchTemplate() function accepts only 8bit or 32bit floating point  type it's mentioned in the docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be)

> **In matchTemplate() > Parameters > Image:** Image where the search is running. It must be 8-bit or 32-bit floating-point.

Also in your error you can spot the assert statement checking if the depth = CV_8U or CV_32F

> error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'

Comment: Thank you @ssh! Is there any way template matching will work with a 16-bit image?

Comment: You could try other libs such as scikit-image which have similar methods, but if that doesn't work then try converting images to float and continue with opencv.

Answer (score 1):

`matchTemplate` accepts 32 bit floating point (besides uint8). FP32 has 23 bits of mantissa, so your 16 bit values fit in there *without any loss of precision*.

Convert to `np.float32` with this: `img.astype(np.float32)`